# Set up Facebook login using .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

**Detail about project:** I am using ASP.NET Core 6. I set up a identity web project and I'm trying to create a Facebook login. I am using following Microsoft 4 steps [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**Issue:** when I click on Facebook login button, the page refreshes, but nothing happens. Did I missed any step?

`https://localhost:7000/signin-facebook` is giving me this:

```
Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

- Step #1: created a Facebook app > get app ID & App secret > set up privacy policy URL

[image]

- Step #2: get advanced access for `public_profile`:

[image]

- Step #3: get redirect URL from Visual Studio under debug option:

[image]

- Step #4: config inside `program.cs` file

  ```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(Options =>
            {
                Options.AppId = "87996242323333695";
                Options.AppSecret = "7c539cd1111111111111115";
            });
  ```

Comment: How are you serving the [`ChallengeResult`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Web/V3/AccountController.cs#L349)? [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L224) where the external login is handled

Comment: Ah no, you're mistaken. `/signin-facebook` is the callback path. You need to navigate to a url, handle this url through an endpoint where you return a `Challenge()`. I've created a [template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates#installing-the-templates) but it's with identityserver, but [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/blob/master/src/content/Application/Web/Server/Controllers/Web/V1/AccountController.cs#L54) it's implemented as well